# Указать диапазон для третьего параметра srtncpy

Tags: c, строки

Как сделать так, чтобы `strncpy` копировал байты из указанного диапазона, например,
от восьмого до шестнадцатого, а не просто от нулевого до указанного в третьем параметре в вызове функции

```
strncpy(num2and1, num2, 33);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
strncpy(num2and1, num2+8, 9);
```

Указываете, откуда и сколько...